# What is the correct way to handle significant figures when calculating compound uncertainties?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, error-analysis, data

When processing experimental data, and calculating an uncertainty value in multiple steps, should intermediary uncertainties be used to a certain number of [significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) or kept to the full precision allowed by the calculator/computer?

I have a number of measured values and their associated uncertainties, and I have processed this data to give me a final value and uncertainty without ever limiting significant figures in either the values or uncertainties at each step. Is this the correct way to go about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do I apply Significant figures in physics calculations?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52837/)

Answer (score 1):

Do the calculation at the computer/calculator precision then quote result with the appropriate number of significant figures. Yes that is correct procedure. Otherwise you could introduce rounding error.

Comment: @user43836 You should read the post linked by Kyle Kanos in the comment to your post that explains why you should not be doing it in  "multiple steps" if possible.