# Significant figures in measurement with error

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements, error-analysis

Someone can explain me what's the rule behind the correct expression of a quantity $K$ with its error $\Delta K$ as $K \pm \Delta K$? 
They must have the same number of significant figures? Or the error should have in general 1-2 significant figures? For example, if I have:

$$K = 8510.33 \pm 56.97~.$$ 
This expression is uncorrect? Maybe should be expressed as: $$K= 8510 \pm 57~? $$

Comment: Related http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32078/2451 and links therein.

Comment: and to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101922/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is usually express as 1 or 2 significant figures.

4 significant figures are too many, because it is unreasonable to think the error could be quantified to such a degree.

Comment: So the general use is simply to express the error with 1-2 significant figures and therefore crop the quantity to the same floating point?

Comment: yes.  Some teachers/instructors only want to see 1 digit, like: http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~labgroup/pdf/Error_analysis.htm  Some want to see 1 digit, unless the digit is a "1" or a "2", in which case they want to see two digits.  Published results often use two digits, sometimes use only one.  Any more than two digits is too many.